# Rails / Paperclip - skipping image processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can I  skip post processing based on a virtual attribute?

My virtual attribute is always nil in the before_asset_post_process callback

Create

```
attachment = Attachment.create(asset: File.open(file.png), :skip_thumb => 1)
```

Attachable model

```
class Attachment < AR::Base
 attr_accessor :skip_thumb

  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => lambda  { |attachment| { :thumb =>  ["100>", 'jpg'] ,
                                                                       :thumb_big =>   ["200>", 'jpg']
                                                                     }
  before_asset_post_process :proceed_or_cancel

  def proceed_or_cancel
    #self.skip_thumb is always nil
    if (self.skip_thumb.present?)
      return false 
    end
  end 

end
```

Comment: It seems to be because attributes don't get set until after before_asset_post_process

Comment: I found details in this issue in the Paperclip repo, which shed light on the issue https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1279 

"The timing of the processing depends on when the attachment is mass-assigned, since processing happens on assignment, not on save."

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `attr_accessible` in your `Attachment` model?
If so, and if it does not include `skip_thumb` this fails (silently) when you try to assign it via mass assignment.

The opposite of `attr_accessible` is `attr_protected`, if you have `skip_thumb` in there, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of `:asset` will happen before the assignment of `:skip_thumb` if it's first in the hash that you pass to `Attachment.create()`. Therefore, it will work if you change your code to:

```
attachment = Attachment.create(skip_thumb: 1, asset: File.open(file.png))
```

I hope this is not too late to be useful...