# Speeding up paperclip seeds on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

We have a lot of seed data for items that use paperclip for photos (real seed data, not sample data). We're set up to use S3 with paperclip as well. Loading our seeds the [commonly suggested way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053138/using-paperclip-within-seeds-rb) is terribly slow already, and we're about to add a ton more items. Seeds already take ~5 minutes to run, so it'll probably take an hour or two after this, which makes the standard git branching style workflow really impractical. We could turn of S3 for development mode, but would rather keep `development` environment as close to `production` if possible.

I've been looking through the paperclip documentation to find out if there's a way we can reuse S3 links without having to go through the process of uploading every time, and haven't found anything. Is there a paperclip "standard" or friendly way to solve this? How have you solved large amount of seed files using Paperclip/S3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, Paper Clip just stores the filename of your image in a column in the database.  If that is the case, then you can seed the database once, using the "commonly suggested method".  After Paper Clip seeds your database and uploads the data to S3, you can query your database for the file names, file sizes, and other file metadata.

You can then generate a new seed file using the existing data in your database to assign record values directly (i.e. not leveraging Paperclip).

To enable creating new records without Paperclip processing them, I recommend following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203171/rails-paperclip-skipping-image-processing).  Add the following to your model:

```
attr_accessor :skip_image_processing

before_asset_post_process :skip_image_processing?

def skip_image_processing?
  self.skip_image_processing
end
```

You may even be able to generate this second seed file automatically with something like this:

```
@images_we_want_to_seed.each do |img|
   puts "Image.create("
   puts "  skip_image_processing: true,
   puts "  asset_file_name: img.asset_file_name,
   puts "  asset_file_size: img.asset_file_size,
   puts "  asset_content_type: image.asset_content_type,
     ....
   puts ")"
   puts " "
end
```

I have not tested, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using `before_*_post_process` is a thoughtful idea, but unfortunately that doesn't prevent the file from being uploaded to S3, only the image processing (which we don't use). 

In addition, Paperclip does store the filename in the database, but it doesn't store the unique id that S3 gives to the files. In the database, it's `Something.jpg`, but on S3 it's `Something.jpg?1509052552`. Restoring the database with seeds dumped from the database does not work, unfortunately.